# Parameter 0 of constructor in RestAuditFilterConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following Spring Service:

Interface copied from external jar:

```
public interface Masker {

  String maskContent(String contentType, String content);

  Map<String, List<String>> maskHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> headers);

}
```

Implementation:

```
@Service
public class MaskerImpl implements Masker {

  private final List<String> maskers;

  private final String headerMasker;

  public MaskerImpl(List<String> maskers, String headerMasker) {
    Collections.sort(maskers, AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
    this.maskers = maskers;
    this.headerMasker = headerMasker;
  }

  @Override
  public String maskContent(String contentType, String content, String messageType) {
    return content;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, List<String>> maskHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Config:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MaskerProperties.class)
public class MaskerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  Masker externalMasker(List<String> maskers, String headerMasker) {
    return new MaskerImpl(maskers, headerMasker);
  }

}
```

Small code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/hateos_poc/tree/main/src/main/java/com/hateos/test/impl

But when I start the code I get error:

```
01:23:38.682 [main] DEBUG Reporter[report:37] - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.Masker' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: maskerImpl,externalMasker

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.RestAuditFilterConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - maskerImpl: defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/....../MaskerImpl.class]
    - externalMasker: defined by method 'externalMasker' in com......MaskerConfiguration
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined 2 Masker bean, when you deploy your application, the Spring IoC container is confused which bean you are trying to autowire.

You can simply use `@Qualifier` into your class to specify your bean, like this:

```java
@Component
public class YourClass {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("externalMasker")
   private Masker externalMasker;

   // or

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("maskerImpl")
   private Masker maskerImpl;

}
```